# Can't edit rows of Azure database in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms

I can't edit or view rows in an Azure database using SQL Server Management Studio. Am I missing something obvious? The option is not there.

Comment: My answer is more correct @Kode, could you mark mine instead?

Comment: I have the same issue so I use LINQPAD Premium for this: https://www.linqpad.net/Purchase.aspx#EditSqlData .

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[You can now](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2014/12/18/sql-server-2014-management-studio-updated-support-for-the-latest-azure-sql-database-update-v12-preview.aspx), you need to have SSMS 2014 with [Cummulative Update 5](http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/SQL%20Server%202014/nosp/SQLServer2014_RTM_CU5_3011055_12_0_2456_/12.0.2456.0/free/480863_intl_x64_zip.exe) or later. The latest CU is always listed on the ["SQL Server 2014 build versions" KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2936603).

Comment: Great knowing Microsoft is listening... but from the thread it seems the hotfix is still too hot for me right now... will wait for it to mature first. Right now I am sticking with Visual Studio Sql Explorer for now.

Comment: For Update 6: http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/SQL%20Server%202014/nosp/SQLServer2014_RTM_CU6_3031047_12_0_2480_/12.0.2480.0/free/482290_intl_x64_zip.exe

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to the items `Select Top 1000 Rows` and `Edit Top 200 Rows` in the contextual menu of a table, they are not available on Microsoft Azure Databases. You should use SQL statements to retrieve/modify your data.

**Update**: as of 18-Dec-2014 you can do this with the latest SSMS: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2014/12/18/sql-server-2014-management-studio-updated-support-for-the-latest-azure-sql-database-update-v12-preview.aspx

Comment: Just curious: Would there be any reason that those options have been made unavailable?

Comment: Don´t really know... There are many other options from that contextual menu that are unavailable (when comparing Azure databases with SQL Server DBs).

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. Hoping that this becomes available, but in the least it will refresh/increase my SQL skills.

Comment: They added support now http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2014/12/18/sql-server-2014-management-studio-updated-support-for-the-latest-azure-sql-database-update-v12-preview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you can't for some reason download the hotfix,  there is a workaround.

If you create a view, you will get the "Edit rows" context menu back.  Then you can use the editor that opens to create queries against the actual table as usual.

Answer (score 0):

SSMS 2016 also suffered from this issue. The latest CU (SP1 CU4) fixed it for me.